# Alternative to JavaScript in means of AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wanted to ask if there is any alternative to JavaScript/AJAX. 
My goal is to have functionality of dynamic content without reloading the page. My problem with JavaScript/Flash or any other plug-ins is that user can disable those.

I already did some research and found [Google Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/) but this is implemented through JavaScript so it doesn't help.

TL;DR - I want an alternative to JavaScript/AJAX, which cant be disabled so that every user will see the same web page without having disadvantages through disabling plug-ins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing like what you're describing that a user cannot disable. Nor should there be. Users should be the ultimate arbiters of what runs on their machines.

JavaScript and Ajax is your most broadly-supported solution. Yes, users can disable it, but globally, [fewer than 2% do](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/) and it's easy to detect that they have and present a non-JavaScript version of your page (or a message saying your page isn't accessible without). Also, note that JavaScript is *not* a plug-in for web browsers; all popular browsers (and most niche browsers) support it natively.

Flash would be your next stop, but despite the Flash plug-in having great penetration there are more users without Flash than without JavaScript (anyone using an iPhone or iPad, for instance). Also, since Flash has been used so heavily for irritating advertising, a lot of people install Flash blockers that prevent the Flash app from running by default, requiring them to click on it to run it. (And of course Flash is closed and proprietary.)

There's also Silverlight from Microsoft (also a plug-in) and the open-source version Moonlight, but there are a lot more people without Silverlight/Moonlight than without Flash.

At the end of the day, you need code running on the end-user's computer, which means they control whether that code is allowed to run — by enabling/disabling JavaScript, by installing or not installing Flash (and using or not using Flash blockers, since it's used for so much irritating advertising), etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternative to "client side programming" for doing "client side actions". Evey option that exists (JS, Flash, Shockwave, Silverlight, Unity, Dart, etc.) can also be disabled.

The purpose of this is to allow the user to control every data request himself and protect him from JS or 3rd party plugins security flaws.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not meant to show page content to the user. For that you have HTML.

It's not even meant to style the page. There is CSS for that.

With HTML and CSS the page content can be seen by search engines, and by people using different devices and browsing methods thanks to CSS, even impaired users.

JavaScript is meant to enhance the functionalities of a web page by allowing a smoother navigation for the user. It should not be used to show content impossible to see if JS is being disabled.

If using AJAX, be sure that each content loaded with AJAX may also be accessible if a user has JS disabled using normal links.

First develop your pages without thinking about JavaScript or other scripting/plugins technologies. Let your pages be fully navigable for every user and every browser.

Then, use JavaScript to enhance the site navigation and give users with JS enabled the best user experience possible.